# Equivelance relation between integrals

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ be an integrable function

Let $G(x)=\int^x_a \int^s _a f(s,t)\,dt\,ds$.

I need to show that this can also be written as $G(x)=\int^x_a\int^x_t f(s,t)\,ds\,dt$.

I have no idea how to solve this problem. My guess is that I need to flip the integral in some way, but I do not know how to do that. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you graphed the region of integration what would it look like?

You have a triangular region bounded by.
t = a , t = s, and s = x

When we change the order of integration, and what does that are the limits?